# Skipping every nth row and copy/transform data into another matrix

Tags: python

I've extracted information from 142 different files, which is stored in CSV-file with one column, which contains both number and text. I want to copy row 11-145, transform it, and paste it into another file (xlsx or csv doesn't matter). Then, I want to skip the next 10 rows, and copy row 156-290, transform and paste it etc etc. I have tried the following code:

```
import numpy as np

overview = np.zeros((145, 135))
for i in original:
    original[i+11:i+145, 1] = overview[1, i+1:i+135]
    print(overview)
```

The `original` file is the imported file, for which I used `pd.read_csv`.

Comment: you are assigning the contents of `overview` (which is 0) to the matrix original. The assignment should be the oposite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pd.read_csv is a function that returns a dataframe.
To select specific rows from a dataframe you can use this function :

df.loc[start:stop:step]
so it would look something like this :

```
df = pd.read_csv(your_file)
new_df = df.loc[11:140]
#transform it as you please

#convert it to excel or csv
new_df .to_excel("new_file.xlsx") or new_df .to_csv("new_file.csv")
```